# How to handle that the application is minimized by HOME button

Tags: android, gps, android-homebutton

An issue has appeared a few days ago.
I have an application that listen for GPS location. The listener is a background service that works all the time, this service saves data in application level and each activity reads this data. So, when i press back button i am able to catch this event and i can stop the service, but when i press HOME button the service is still working although the application is in background mode and this consumes battery, because the GPS always works. How can i handle this event? I do want to stop all services when the user presses HOME button and start them again when user gets back.
10x

Comment: Its a very old question and seems unanswered.
Just trying to give my best solution:
I understand problem is not handling home button, rather get the event of application going in background. Android give handle for events like background and foreground of application and I suggest you to use this to disable and enable your service respectively.
I hope this helps :)

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you're catching the back button either via an onKey... method or in onStop. You should place your code in the [onPause()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPause%28%29) method to ensure it's used whenever the app gets backgrounded.

Comment: Likewise, you will have to (re-)start those services in `onResume()`.

Comment: I can't put my code in onPause() method, because when i start a new activity, the old one will stop the service. And what happens if the new activity needs GPS information too?

Comment: The new one could restart it. It's the same logic as when you press the back button and the user goes to a previous activity which needed the service.

Answer (score 4):

You can not handle home button events in your Android application. Google has made it for internal use only.

[LINK 1](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=1979)
[LINK 2](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html#KEYCODE_HOME)

Answer (score 2):

```
   @Override
    protected void onUserLeaveHint() 
   { 
        // When user presses home page
        Log.v(TAG, "Home Button Pressed");
        super.onUserLeaveHint();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a OnKeyListener, and check if the pressed key was Home. I never tried it, though.

Answer (score 0):

create a custom activity called customActivity extends Activity  now override method(in customActivity) to catch home button event and stop your service(create & start service in application class). Now extends customActivity instead of Activity for any activity_class.

Comment: Dude, there is no event for Home button.

Answer (score -5):

Long press the HOME button, it will enlist the running process, select the one you want and then exit it gracefully.

OR
From Home -> settings -> application -> manage application
you can kill the unwanted process.

Comment: Haha I know this is an old post but this actually made me laugh out VERY loud!